# UIWebView fast scrolling to show large image lead to memory warning crash

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

When I'm testing my app on `iPhone6 Plus (iOS 8.4.1,Xcode 7.2.1)`,I find when I'm scrolling the webView **FAST** (scrolling slowly have nothing wrong) to show two large images,I receive memory warning and it crashes.(the page is also filled with large number of other small images)

**But** on `iPhone4s(iOS 7.1)` and `iPhone5s(iOS 9.2.1)` there is no problem doing the same operation.

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

I try this to fix memory warning but still not work

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self fixMemoryWarningCrashMethod];
}
    - (void)fixMemoryWarningCrashMethod
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"WebKitCacheModelPreferenceKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"WebKitOfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code and particular error messages you receive.

Comment: Please post key codes or the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I spare no effort to solve this,including cleaning cache in memory and disk,it's a reality that UIWebView does have high memory occupy - problem.So I leave it to html developer to make the page fit to big-screen iPhone